# QtWebkit build failed on Windows

Tags: qt, webkit

acutal i try to build qtwebkit on windows 7 with VS 2013.
I follow the instruction of this site https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnWindows

After a while the build failed because the WebkitSystemInterface.h cannot be find. So i take a look in the perl scripts and see that the copy-webkitlibraries-to-product-directory dont work. The Reason is that this script use OSX commands like ditto and xcrun.

So i manually copy to the path, which stand in the copy script and edit the projects includes. With the next try to build the error the WebkitSystemInterface.h can't find several dependencies, classes etc.

Is it actual possible to build QtWebkit on an Windows machine and got you a hint what i can try next?

best regards

Comment: Any particular reason you're still using QtWebKit?

Comment: @MrEricSir We need to change to Qt5.6 and QWebEngine replace QtWebkit. QWebEngine actual doesn't support all features of QtWebkit. The important print options will be available at Qt 5.7